# How to check the cell index of a table in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table, addeventlistener

I have a 3 row 4 column table in JavaScript and trying to understand DOM manipulation.  I have the first cell of the table outlined with a thicker border.  I am attempting to add buttons to move the thicker border to another cell.  Right now, I am just focused on a Down button to move the outlined border down a single cell.  I am stumped on what I am doing wrong in the function definition of the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3></h3>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>cell 9</td>
    <td>cell 10</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p></p>


<script>
//variable for the table.
var x = document.getElementById("myTable");

//index for the row number and cell number
var rowIndex= 0;
var cellIndex = 0;

//this outlines the cell's starting position.
x.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex].style.border = "10px solid black";

//creation of the button
var button = document.createElement ("button");
button.innerText = "DOWN"
button.id = "d"
document.body.appendChild(button);

//I am trying to pass x to the function.  Then use the rowIndex and cellIndex to increment by 1
//depending on if the user wants to move the outline border up, down, left, or right.
//I just am trying to get the down button first.
button.addEventListener ("click", function(x){

//The purpose here is to change the outlined cell back to the default border of the table.
x.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex].style.border = "1px solid black";

//The purpose here is to select the cell immediately below to outline it.
x.rows[rowIndex+1].cells[cellIndex].style.border = "thick solid black";

}
);




</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass *x* to the event handler function. When passing *x*, the function creates a new variable with that name which is scoped to the function, that is not the actual *x* defined in the global scope, that refers to the table. You can either rename the parameter name or remove that as you are not using that inside the function:

```js
//variable for the table.
var x = document.getElementById("myTable");

//index for the row number and cell number
var rowIndex= 0;
var cellIndex = 0;

//this outlines the cell's starting position.
x.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex].style.border = "10px solid black";

//creation of the button
var button = document.createElement ("button");
button.innerText = "DOWN"
button.id = "d"
document.body.appendChild(button);

//I am trying to pass x to the function.  Then use the rowIndex and cellIndex to increment by 1
//depending on if the user wants to move the outline border up, down, left, or right.
//I just am trying to get the down button first.
button.addEventListener ("click", function(e){
    if(x.rows.length-1 == rowIndex) return false; // return if last row selected;
    //The purpose here is to change the outlined cell back to the default border of the table.
    x.rows[rowIndex].cells[cellIndex].style.border = "1px solid black";
    
    //The purpose here is to select the cell immediately below to outline it.
    x.rows[rowIndex+1].cells[cellIndex].style.border = "thick solid black";
    rowIndex++; // Increment the index
  }
);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td>cell 2</td>
    <td>cell 3</td>
    <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 5</td>
    <td>cell 6</td>
    <td>cell 7</td>
    <td>cell 8</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>cell 9</td>
    <td>cell 10</td>
    <td>cell 11</td>
    <td>cell 12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```